# How can I find out where a type, data constructor or typeclass is defined?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to figure out where the LayoutClass type or data constructor is defined for XMonad https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.12/docs/XMonad-Core.html#t:LayoutClass.

I've also tried using ghci with no success:

```
Prelude> import XMonad.Core
Prelude XMonad.Core> :t LayoutClass

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: LayoutClass
Prelude XMonad.Core>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LayoutClass` is not a data type or a type constructor. It is a typeclass. You can verify it by clicking the `Source` button to the right of a row starting with `LayoutClass` in an `Instances` table in the documentation. For example, this is the first line of code for row starting with `LayoutClass Layout Window`

```
instance LayoutClass Layout Window where
```

This means that `Layout Window` is an instance of the `LayoutClass` typeclass.

Comment: Is there a way to find where a type class is defined via ghci?

Comment: Using `:i` works for any type constructor, value constructor, class name, function or method, and usually tells you something interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "source" link on the right of the line you linked, in this case to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.12/docs/src/XMonad-Core.html#LayoutClass

Answer (score 0):

Hoogle is often used for this purpose:
http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=LayoutClass

But it does not seem to index all available packages on hackage.

The above typeclass is indexed by the latest (in Alpha for now) Hoogle:
http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=LayoutClass

You can also search the stackage Hoogle:
https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.11/hoogle?q=LayoutClass